# php mongodb find - return calculated value

Tags: php, mongodb, date-arithmetic

In PHP -> MongoDB, how do I return a field as a calculated value?

```
$this->Collection = $this->db->$theDB;  
$cursor = $this->Collection->find();
```

For example, one of my fields is date of birth:

```
DOB : 1/1/1980
```

Instead, I want to get back the AGE.   Current Date - DOB = AGE.

Is this possible / how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a [map-reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) and process the age like that

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

How about just create method that will return to you age from dob?

```
getAgeFromDOB(date dob)
{
  return Current Date - dob;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it would be more efficient to have mongodb return the age as a column for me, but sure, I can iterate through the data in php and do the calculation myself.

Comment: @ScottSzretter: If you no need query on Age i guess it does not make sence store Age in mongodb and recalculate it in background..